# Prolog labeling gives redundant solutions in prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have a homework to do for school, which is as follow :
Anne and Michel are people who organize a dinner with a bunch of 
couples. They have to be placed face to face on the table.

Men also have to alternate with women, married people cannot be 
neighbors, same for incompatible persons. Finally, neighbors also 
have to share at least one hobby.

My solutions seems to work, but I have two problems : 
first, when I produce solutions with 'go.' and then press ';', I receive too many solutions (seems to round in circles...). Second, when I remove one couple (in commented part) the solution comes after a very long time... I can't see any explanation about those behaviour, but I've only discovered Prolog two monthes ago. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Program can be tried here...](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/table_plan.pl)

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                        MAIN PREDICATE                                  %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

go :- Guests = [  manon, alice, juliette, lucie, charlotte, olivia, margaux,
                     jules, hugo, tom, louis, paul, jean, antoine  ],
%go :- Guests = [  alice, juliette, lucie, charlotte, olivia, margaux,
%                     hugo, tom, louis, paul, jean, antoine  ],
      produce_table(Guests).

produce_table(Guests) :-

    length([anne, michel|Guests],Nb),
    produce_assoc_list([anne, michel|Guests],La,Nb),

    reduce_domain(La,Nb),
    different_places(La),
    label_places(La),

    sort(2,@<,La,La_trie),
    print_table(La_trie).

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                          ASSOCIATIVE LIST                              %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

produce_assoc_list([],[],_) :- !.
produce_assoc_list([N|L],[pers(N,P)|La],Nb) :-
    P in 1..Nb,
    ( N == anne -> P#=1
    ; true),
    ( N == michel -> P*2 #>= Nb, P*2 #=< Nb+2
    ; true),
    produce_assoc_list(L,La,Nb).

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                               CONSTRAINTS                              %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

reduce_domain_aux(_,[],_) :- !.
reduce_domain_aux(pers(N1,P1),[pers(N2,P2)|T],Nb) :-
    gender(N1,S1),gender(N2,S2),
    ( S1==S2 -> separate_neighbors(P1,P2,Nb)
    ; true),

    hobby(N1,H1),hobby(N2,H2),
    intersection(H1,H2,I),
    ( I==[] -> separate_neighbors(P1,P2,Nb)
    ; true),

    ( married(N1,N2) -> separate_neighbors(P1,P2,Nb)
    ; true),

    ( incompatibles(N1,N2) -> separate_neighbors(P1,P2,Nb)
    ; true),

    reduce_domain_aux(pers(N1,P1),T,Nb).

reduce_domain([],_) :- !.
reduce_domain([H|T],Nb) :-
    reduce_domain_aux(H,T,Nb),
    reduce_domain(T,Nb).


% Persons at different places
% ----------------------------------

vars_list([],[]) :- !.
vars_list([pers(_,P)|T],[P|L]) :-
    vars_list(T,L).

different_places(Lp) :-
    vars_list(Lp,Lv),
    all_distinct(Lv).

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                                LABELING                                %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

label_places(Lp) :-
    vars_list(Lp,Lv),
    label(Lv).

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                            USEFULL PREDICATES                          %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

married(X,Y) :-
    spouses(X,Y);spouses(Y,X), !.

incompatibles(X,Y) :-
    incompatible(X,Y); incompatible(Y,X), !.

separate_neighbors(P1,P2,Nb) :- 
    P1  #\= (P2+1) mod Nb,
    P1  #\= (P2-1) mod Nb.

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                                PRINT RESULTS                           %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

print_table([]) :- !, nl.
print_table([pers(N,P)|T]) :-
    nl, format('~w ~d ~w ~a ',['Place ',P, ' :', N]),
    print_table(T).

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%                                                                        %
%                            DATABASE                                    %
%                                                                        %
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %

spouses(anne,michel).
spouses(manon,jules).
spouses(alice,hugo).
spouses(juliette,tom).
spouses(lucie,louis).
spouses(charlotte,paul).
spouses(olivia,jean).
spouses(margaux,antoine).

gender(anne,f).
gender(manon,f).
gender(alice,f).
gender(juliette,f).
gender(lucie,f).
gender(charlotte,f).
gender(olivia,f).
gender(margaux,f).

gender(michel,m).
gender(jules,m).
gender(hugo,m).
gender(tom,m).
gender(louis,m).
gender(paul,m).
gender(jean,m).
gender(antoine,m).

hobby(anne,[sport,jardinage,voyages]).
hobby(manon,[jardinage,voyages]).
hobby(alice,[jardinage,voyages]).
hobby(juliette,[sport,voyages]).
hobby(lucie,[jardinage]).
hobby(charlotte,[jardinage]).
hobby(olivia,[sport,jardinage]).
hobby(margaux,[sport]).

hobby(michel,[sport,jardinage,voyages]).
hobby(jules,[sport,jardinage]).
hobby(hugo,[sport,jardinage]).
hobby(tom,[sport,voyages]).
hobby(louis,[sport,jardinage]).
hobby(paul,[sport]).
hobby(jean,[sport,jardinage]).
hobby(antoine,[sport,jardinage]).

incompatible(manon,louis).
incompatible(charlotte,antoine).
incompatible(margaux,hugo).
```

Comment: cuts don't play well with CLP(FD), and anyway you should try to remove *all* of them, specially when you don't understand their purpose.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I just tried what you suggest, but it doesn't seem to change anything...